# Как исправить перенос строк в phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm, настройки, форматирование-кода

При скачивании проекта с сервера (использую FileZilla), появляются лишние пустые строки в коде. Файл всегда имеет свои переносы (CR) и преобразить уже имеющийся код на переносы CRLF не удается. Подскажите, что я делаю не так и возможно ли это в принципе[image: скрин отображения кода]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заходите в настройки, `Editor=>Code Style=>HTML` вкладка `OTHER`
Там указываете, перед какими тегами вставлять пустую строку, а перед какими нет, и так же можно добавить перед какими тегами удалять поля. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В настройках это поле уже без единого тега, но это ничего не исправило. Эти настройки отвечают только за новый код или же должны влиять и на загруженный? Могут ли эти сноски подтягиваться с последнего сохранения файлов на сервере? (Мол, если там они есть, то, следовательно, их уже не убрать)

Comment: @МаксВетр это действует при заполнении файла и переноса данных. Если код уже  в PhpStorm и необходимо удалить лишние, то Вы можете использовать автоформатирование кода `Ctrl+Alt+L`